# How anonymous used UTF-16 ASCII to fool PHP escaping

Tags: php, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How anonymous used UTF-16 ASCII to fool PHP escaping](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11391/how-anonymous-used-utf-16-ascii-to-fool-php-escaping)

(Reposted here as per [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119326/how-anonymous-used-utf-16-ascii-to-fool-php-escaping/9136293#9136293)). A few months ago, anonymous took down a child pornography site using SQL-injection. I read in [this](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2011/10/anonymous-takes-down-darknet-child-porn-site-on-tor-network.ars) article that anonymous claimed that "the server was using hardened PHP with escaping," but they were able to "bypass it with with UTF-16 ASCII encoding." What does that mean Anonymous, exactly? How do I protect my site from a similar attack?